# LitElement with router not working on page reload

Tags: web-component, lit

I have used the Open Web Components bootstrap https://github.com/open-wc/open-wc/ to set up a web components based app.

I have tried the following router libraries:

https://github.com/vaadin/router

https://github.com/hamedasemi/lit-element-router

Both work fine for dev mode `npm run start`

If I do an `npm run build` the routing works fine when clicking links but when I go directly to a sub route of the homepage, or reload the page for anything other than the homepage, I get a 404

Is there a recommended approach to routing for a web components app?

I had used this tutorial https://www.thisdot.co/blog/routing-management-with-litelement/ and you can see the 404 behaviour if running a build version of the github source.

Comment: How are you serving the built site? You likely need to configure the server to serve up the `index.html` on those other routes besides `/`.